# Problem while loading Application into VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

Hope you all are fine and also in one of your best of moods!!

I am Working as an iPhone Developer, I have to develope an application which is already developed in VB 6.0, I have given individual forms of application, and I called to get Ideas and Requirements by Compiling that VB Application.

Please have a look at issue that i face during loading VB forms.

Issue:

I have installed VB6.0 in my PC. and While i am trying to open that forms(.frm&.frx) in VB it shows an error Like

```
IngotTextBoxCtl.dll
IngotComboBoxCtl.dll
IngotListBoxCtl.dll
IngotLabelCtl.dll
IngotOwnerDrawGridCtl.dll
IngotgridCtl.dll
IngotButtonCtl.dll
IngotCheckBoxCtl.dll
IngotRadioButtonCtl.dll
IngotHSScrollBarCtl.dll
```

Could not be loaded or open.

I don't know what all are this for.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing control libraries for the Ingot controls, you will need to track down the assemblies and install / register them on your system, then ensure that the Components are available in the project via Project > Components.